# Make server-side validation without losing data on postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation, file-upload

I would like to know which is the best way to do this: I have a form using ASP that is being validated firstly on **client-side** with jQuery. In this form I have a FileUpload control to upload an Excel file and the validation of this control is being made on **server-side** to check the file type, valid data, valid structure, etc... I really need to make the file validation on server-side to be as secure as possible and I don't want to use ActiveX.

The problem is that, when the server-side validation returns an error, the previously inserted data in the form is lost due to the postback.

Is there a way to make client-side validation, then after this is done, make the server-side validation and on the postback don't lose the sent data?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do that is to get old values of field at Page_Load.
All you have to is check if page is postback.

```
     if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        YourTextBox.Attributes.Add("Value", YourTextBox.Text);
    }
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a CustomValidator to you form that will call the FileUpload.SaveAs() method and that will validate the uploaded file.

For example:

```
protected void ValidateCstm_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{

    //Upload the file
    fileUpload1.SaveAs(....
    .....
    .....

    //Validate the fileUpload
    .....

    //If the fileUpload is invalid
    args.IsValid = false;

}
```

I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using AJAX for the file validation, thus avoiding a full post back altogether?  There are several AJAX-based file upload widgets 'out there' that might serve your purposes...

Answer (score 0):

just when you encountered any error on server side , set all your form post data in some session variable and redirect to the form and show the form filled up with this session data.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use [jQuery File Upload](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) component. It does not require post backs. It needs server to handle HTTP GET, POST and DELETE and return [JSON](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup). You can use [ASHX](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) for this. This way your server side validation will not interfere with post backs.